# First time installing WordPress. Cant Access

Tags: installation

I am testing WordPress in a Virtual Box VM with CentOS 7 as guest. Following the steps in [Link](http://www.itzgeek.com/web/wordpress/install-wordpress-with-nginx-1-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html) .I did Prerequisites number 1 and tested successfully. I did the rest of the steps in database creation etc. But the WordPress start page is not showing what ever I try.

Please advise me. And I will provide what ever information are needed.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please provide more details of what exactly is happening? Just a bit hard to decode what you did and what went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start looking is always the error log of your web server.

But for the moment, the best place to start looking is the nginx log file, which according to the howto article you are linking to is here:

```
#  less /usr/share/nginx/$domain/logs/error.log
```

If there is no log file, check if the folder exists and the nginx process can write towards that file / directory.

In case you can't get to the logs, it would be nice to know more about the error code you are seeing when you try to access with your browser.

Comment: And - just let me add this as a personal comment: 
Since you are trying to use Nginx instead of Appache, you'll find less resources on the web to help you get Wordpress up and running and later maintain it. You might want to use the standard "LAMP" environment for your first steps into Wordpress.